# Pyspark dynamically create new columns and apply transforms

Tags: pyspark

I am using pyspark structured streaming to read kafka messages.  I am new to pyspark and trying to figure out the most performant way to dynamically add columns based upon a set of instructions (JSON) contained in the kafaka message.  I believe I need to leverage UDFs to accomplish these transformations which rely on numpy, pandas and ta-lib.  I've also read that that UDFs can cause performance issues when switching from the Spark JVM to the Python interpreter.  Any advice is appreciated.

Kafka message:

```
{
  "type" : "crypto",
  "source" : "bitfinex",
  "symbol" : "BTCUSD",
  "date" : "2021-07-19 22:56:00",
  "open" : 30905,
  "close" : 30906.74505157,
  "high" : 30914,
  "low" : 30904,
  "volume" : 5.35799558,
  "pipeline": {
        "transforms": [
            {"name": "SMA_5", "transform": "SMA", "line": "close", "period": 5, "lookback": 100},
            {"name": "SMA_15", "transform": "SMA", "line": "close", "period": 15, "lookback": 100},
            {"name": "EMA_5", "transform": "EMA", "line": "close", "period": 5, "lookback": 100},
            {"name": "EMA_15", "transform": "EMA", "line": "close", "period": 15, "lookback": 100},
            {"name": "APO", "transform": "APO", "line": "close", "lookback": 100},
            {"name": "PSAR", "transform": "PSAR", "lookback": 100}
        ]
    }
}
```

Each "name" in the transforms array will become a new column in the dataframe.  I think it would be best if I can call one UDF that performs all the necessary transforms and returns the results as multiple columns.

NOTE: the pipeline transformations array is not static and will change from message to message.

My pyspark code thus far:

```
import json
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as T

KAFKA_HOST = "kafka1:19092"
TOPIC = "crypto"

schema = T.StructType(
  {
    T.StructField("type", T.StringType()),
    T.StructField("source", T.StringType()),
    T.StructField("symbol", T.StringType()),
    T.StructField("date", T.StringType()),
    T.StructField("open", T.DoubleType()),
    T.StructField("close", T.DoubleType()),
    T.StructField("high", T.DoubleType()),
    T.StructField("low", T.DoubleType()),
    T.StructField("volume", T.DoubleType()),
    T.StructField("pipeline", T.StringType()),
  }
)

# initializing Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("KafkaTest").getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel('WARN')

# Subscribe to 1 topic
df = spark.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", KAFKA_HOST).option("subscribe", TOPIC).load()

# Cast the value to string
df = df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING) as json")

# Parse the json string and apply schema
df2 = df.withColumn("json", F.from_json(df["json"], schema)).select("json.*")

# Apply transforms

# Log the output
writer = df2.writeStream.outputMode("append").format("console").start()

# Exit
writer.awaitTermination()
```

The dataframe output before any transformations:

```
Batch: 1
-------------------------------------------
+-------+-------+------+-------+--------------------+-------------------+--------------+--------+----------+------+
|   open|    low|  type|   high|            pipeline|               date|         close|  source|    volume|symbol|
+-------+-------+------+-------+--------------------+-------------------+--------------+--------+----------+------+
|30905.0|30904.0|crypto|30914.0|{"transforms":[{"...|2021-07-19 22:56:00|30906.74505157|bitfinex|5.35799558|BTCUSD|
+-------+-------+------+-------+--------------------+-------------------+--------------+--------+----------+------+
```

As mentioned before, the next dataframe would show the dynamically created columns with their calculated values (SMA_5, SMA_15, EMA_5, EMA_15, APO).

** UDPATE **

Going with this approach for now to save the transforms as json in a new column...

```
# Apply transforms
def pipeline_func(pipeline):
  arr = json.loads(pipeline)["transforms"]
  results = {"transforms": []}
  for t in arr:
    results["transforms"].append({"name": t["name"], "value": 100})
  return json.dumps(results)

pipeline_udf = F.udf(pipeline_func, T.StringType())

df3 = df2.withColumn("pipeline_result", pipeline_udf(df2.pipeline)).select("pipeline_result")
```

Comment: How are u planning to use this columns that you create from the json?

Comment: I am going to write them back to Kafka